# How to plot a butterfly plot or symmetric barchart in R

Tags: r, gnuplot

I need to create a bargraph with middle x-axis and two positive y axis above and below.
It should look like a [butterfly plot in SAS](http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/files/2012/07/Butterfly.png), but transposed x and y axis.
My data is lengths of male and female fish.

Sample data:

```
length <- c(12,13,15,14,13,16,18) 
sex<-c("m","m","m","f","f","f","f") 
dat=data.frame(length,sex)
```

Comment: Please include your data set or some sort of play data set for us to work with.

Comment: length <- c(12,13,15,14,13,16,18)
sex<-c("m","m","m","f","f","f","f")
dat=data.frame(length,sex)
ggplot(dat, aes(length, fill=sex)) +  geom_bar()

what i actually need is male and female value on two sides of horizontal x-axis

Answer (score 5):

Another term is 'opposed horizontal barchart'. (There are multiple authors to package: plotrix but Jim Lemon stands out as the most productive and is both the maintainer of the package and the author of `pyramid.plot`.) This is a modified version of an example in `?pyramid.plot`:

```
install.packages("plotrix")
xy.pop<-c(3.2,3.5,3.6,3.6,3.5,3.5,3.9,3.7,3.9,3.5,3.2,2.8,2.2,1.8,
  1.5,1.3,0.7,0.4)
 xx.pop<-c(3.2,3.4,3.5,3.5,3.5,3.7,4,3.8,3.9,3.6,3.2,2.5,2,1.7,1.5,
  1.3,1,0.8)
 agelabels<-c("0-4","5-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34",
  "35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69","70-74",
  "75-79","80-44","85+")
 mcol<-plotrix::color.gradient(c(0,0,0.5,1),c(0,0,0.5,1),c(1,1,0.5,1),18)
 fcol<-plotrix::color.gradient(c(1,1,0.5,1),c(0.5,0.5,0.5,1),c(0.5,0.5,0.5,1),18)
 # removed labels in center but you could run the example and see another approach
 par(mar=plotrix::pyramid.plot(xy.pop,xx.pop, labels=rep("",18),
  main="Australian population pyramid 2002",lxcol=mcol,rxcol=fcol,
  gap=0,show.values=TRUE))
```

[image]